# ELI5: Converting an arbitrary gas cost in Remix IDE to USD

Tags: remix, gas, gas-estimate

Let's say the gas (transaction) cost of a function in Remix is `139508`. How would I easily convert this to USD?

I know this is a totally noob question and I know better, but I can't for the life of me seem to get comfortable with the conversion. Can someone outline the exact steps like ELI5? Thanks, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is depended on following factors,

1. Chain you are using
2. Gas price at the time
3. Price of the Native currency of the chain

Let's consider you made the transaction on Ethereum chain just now (2023-11-17T15:17:08Z).

**Current average gas price = 35 Gwei**

**Gas cost for the tx = 139508 x 35 Gwei = 4882780 Gwei = 0.00488278 Eth** (one gwei is 0.000000001 ETH)

**Eth price now = 1,939.08 USD**

**Gas cost = 1,939.08 x 0.00488278 = 9.468 USD**

You can refer: [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/gastracker#chart_gasprice) [Coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/)

Comment: You can also use Gastracker API : https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/gas-tracker

Comment: 9 DOLLARS?! ?!?!?! WHAT IT REALLY IS THAT EXPENSIVE

Comment: I think you can switch chains if the gas cost is too high. In Ethereum it is bit higher due to several factors. Main reason is ETH price is higher.